# How to set up centralized user authentication on Ubuntu?

Tags: authentication, pam, openldap

I have installed OpenLDAP, and configured some basic users. Next, I want to configure users in my directory to be able to authenticate through my server. I was reading a little about something called PAM. Is this what I should use? If so, can someone point me to some good instructions?

Comment: Your question is too broad See https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html and ask if you have a problem or question with some part of that.

Comment: I followed the guide in the "LDAP Authentication" section, but when I try to switch user with "su <username>", I get the error: "No passwd entry for user 'username'"

Comment: Actually, on second try, I got su to work. I had to use a user that was in a posix group, I guess? Not really sure. But, how can I configure it so I can log in to Ubuntu's desktop environment by username and password? Currently, I can log in by selecting my name and providing a password, or a Guest account. Only those two accounts can be logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to do most of this. I followed the instructions at: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html under the "LDAP Authentication" section.

This allowed me to switch user in the terminal to an LDAP user. Then, I edited: /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf to be:

```
[Seat:*]
allow-guest=false
greeter-hide-users=true
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

This gave me an option to log in as another user on the Ubuntu login screen. I was able to log in as an LDAP user named "jdoe".

Comment: That link appears to be dead.